# animate max-width in one css class

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I would like one CSS class that when an element is added to the `document.body` it would animate in with `max-width`

currently I know how to do it with two classes and adding the second class after.  But I need to add many elements to the page and it would be much cleaner to do it with one class.

Id like to convert this to use one class: http://codepen.io/hellomihai/pen/yYBPjW

css:

```
.hide-me {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 0;
}

.show-me {
  max-width: 1000px;
  transition: max-width 5s;
}

.my-stuff {
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.className = 'my-stuff hide-me';
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.my-stuff').addClass('show-me');
  }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean: max-width?

Comment: @PedroAffonso, yes my apologies.  I went through a few edits where I changed it from height to width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using keyframes  you can avoid adding the class the second time [like so](http://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/xwKPyE)!

```
.my-stuff {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: example;
   animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {
   width: 0;
  }
  to {
   width: 600px;
  }
}

keyframes example {
  from {
   width: 0;
  }
  to {
   width: 600px;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

   // want to not use a setTimeout to add a class after
   setTimeout(function() {
        newDiv.className = 'my-stuff';
  }, 1);
 });
```

Comment: using keyframes is the way to go since it only requires a single class for the "appear sliding in" animation.  Please update your answer (based on the second link) and Ill mark it correct.  Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Looks good.  The setTimeout isnt needed.  You can add `newDiv.className = 'my-stuff';` directly to the ready method.

Comment: strictly speaking u don't even need the ready method, if your JS loads after you HTML pen updated BTW

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way around that except hiding each div by default and controlling their appearance with classes. I'd advise against that as it would result in more work for the non-animated elements.

```
div {
    max-width: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I agree, thats why I was hoping theres a way to do it with only one class for the item.  See @sajs answer.  It works well.