# How to animate CSS changes that are triggered by JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs

One can use `refs` in react to control the DOM elements as follows:

```
handleContactMouseEnter = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let ref = //Get the Ref;
    let div = this.refs[ref];
    div.className = "text-left";
  };
```

The problem is that these changes happen very abruptly. I was wondering if there is an easy way to add some animations to the changes that are triggered like this. For example, the aforementioned code changes the alignment of some text. Can I make it look like that text is moving while this change applies?

Comment: @rags2riches Thank you for your comment. I think you couldn't post it completely. Can you please post the solution when you managed to access a computer?

Comment: you can use keyframes like this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262037/animate-max-width-in-one-css-class/32262211#32262211

Comment: I am on mobile and can't post one of the potential solution. This is a possible algorithm: 1. Start with div with class set to "text_position-center 2. Set the text-left class to have a transition of say 0.3s 3. Apply a relative position to the text-left class and set it to say -200px using transform=translate(-200px), which represents the difference between the old and new value of the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"text-right" looks like a bootstrap class, is that what you are using? If not, please post what styling it assigns. If it is bootstrap, then "text-right" alters the text-align attribute, which is an attribute that cannot be animated, see for example: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties

But, as @rags2riches says, a similar effect might be achieved by creating and applying some other styling, for example:

```
.text-box {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.text-box--left {
  transform: translate(-200px);
}
```

In this way, you code example could be altered to:

```
handleContactMouseEnter = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let ref = //Get the Ref;
    let div = this.refs[ref];
    div.className = "text-box--left";
  };
```

I hope that helps. If not, please share some more details about your particular setup and what you are using and hope to achieve.